# approximating smooth functions by non-smooth ones, in the distribution topology

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, approximation-theory, schwartz-distributions

The classical Stone-Weierstrass theorem gives a necessary and sufficient condition for a class of continuous functions on a compact to approximate a larger class of continuous functions in $C^0$ topology. A generalization due to L. Nachbin gives such a condition for $C^r$ topology.

Here is my question: let $A$ be a class of $C^\infty$ functions on a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Can one formulate a condition for functions from a class $B$ of $C^r$ functions to approximate functions from $A$ in the following sense: for any $f \in A$ there exists a sequence $g_i \in B$ so that $g_i, g_i', \ldots, g_i^{(k)}$ converge respectively to $f, f', \ldots, f^{(k)}$, where $k > r$, the derivatives are  in the distributions sense, and convergence is in the distributions topology.

(one can ask a similar question of functions on compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ replacing derivatives with differential operators)

Comment: As stated, this is a strange question. Perhaps you can give some more background. Note that convergence $u_n\to u$ in $\mathscr D'$ automatically implies $u_n^{(k)} \to u^{(k)}$ in $\mathscr D'$ for all $k\in\mathbb N$. This is a trivial but important fact in distribution theory.

Comment: Dear Jochen, I guess your remark makes my question trivial for an application that I have in mind. Unfortunately I cannot add much to motivate the question: I looking to work with [Lagerberg's differential forms](http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.2856) on polyhedral complexes, and I wanted for some reason to approximate arbitrary forms with piecewise affine ones. Since I want to compute differentials of these forms, I wanted the approximations to be compatible in the sense as above, hence this question.

Comment: Dear Jochen, could you enlighten me about the fact you have mentioned? Suppose we have a sequence of continuous functionals $T_i$ converging to $T$, and we have a test function $\varphi$ such that $T_i \varphi$ converges to $T \varphi$. Then we need to show that $T_i \varphi^{(k)}$ converges to $T \varphi^{(k)}$ for all $k$. My guess is that using the bound on the norm of $T_i$-s (since they are continuous and converging to a continuous functional) one bounds $T \varphi^{(k)} - T_i \varphi^{(k)}$ and thus establishes the convergence. Is that so?

Comment: Firs, the space $\mathscr{D}$ is not a normed space  so you cannot speak of the norms of  linear functionals. From the definition of the topology on $\mathscr{D}'$ it follows that  the operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ is continuous on $\mathscr{D}'$. For more details  see L. Schwartz book on distributions.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu: I referred to the usual operator norm of $T_i$'s (which are continuous functionals, so it's well-defined). Thank you, I will check the Schwartz' book.

Comment: The "usual" topology on $\mathscr D'$ is convergence of $u_n(\varphi)\to u(\varphi)$ FOR ALL $\varphi \in \mathscr D$ (this describes the weak$^*$ topology). For $\varphi \in \mathscr D$ the derivatives $\varphi^{(k)}$ again belong to $\mathscr D$, hence $u_n^{(k)}(\varphi)=(-1)^k u_n(\varphi^{(k)}) \to (-1)^{k}u(\varphi^{(k)})=u^{(k)}(\varphi)$.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth: thank you! indeed, a trivial fact